# Measure weight of communities for different subgraphs

Tags: r, igraph

I detect communities in my adjacency matrix. Parallely, I create an affiliation matrix using the vertices of the same matrix. How do I measure the weight of the communities in each of the columns of the affiliation matrix?

Take the following adjacency matrix:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
A   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
B   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
C   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
D   1   1   0   0   1   1   0
E   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
F   1   1   0   1   1   0   1
G   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

I identify the communities:

```
com <- edge.betweenness.community(g)
V(g)$memb <- com$membership
```

Now take the following affiliation matrix:

```
    P   R   Q
A   1   1   0
B   1   0   1
C   1   1   0
D   0   1   0
E   1   0   1
F   0   0   1
G   1   1   0
```

How do I count the number of vertices corresponding to community [[1]] which are affiliated to the "P" in the affiliation matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `sum(m[com[[1]],"P"]>0)`, given that `m` holds your affiliation matrix. Or `lapply(com, function(x) colSums(m[x, ]))` for all communities.